# Why is my form still submitting even though it returns false?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I made this code which submits a form with a name and age field with a submit button. My code looks like this:

```js
function checkForm() {
  var name = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
  var age = document.forms["form"]["age"].value;
  var regName = /^[A-Z]*[a-z]{3,} $/;
  var regAge = /^[\d.*]{1,} $/;

  if (name == regName && age == regAge) {
    return true;

  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="register.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
  <p>Name:</p>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <br>
  <p>Age:</p>
  <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The name should be using only upper case and lower case letters and the age must be numerical and a positive integer.

Supposedly, when I entered the wrong data, the form should not return false but its returning true and sending me through to register.php. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add event.preventDefault(); when the data is invalid.

```
function checkForm(event){
    var name = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
    var age = document.forms["form"]["age"].value;
    var regName = /^[A-Z]*[a-z]{3,} $/;
    var regAge = /^[\d.*]{1,} $/;

    if (name == regName && age == regAge){
        return true;

    } else{
   event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try evaluating regex With `pattern.test('stringMethod')`

```
function checkForm(event){
    var name = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
    var age = document.forms["form"]["age"].value;
    var regName = /^[A-Z]*[a-z]{3,} $/;
    var regAge = /^[\d.*]{1,} $/;
    if (regName.test(name) && regAge.test(age)){
        return true;
    } else{
   event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Form default behaviour is like that if you are calling a function on submit it will get submit. So you can call the function on button submit.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="return checkForm()">Submit</button>
```